# Use max_by in Ruby to find the key for the maximum number in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, dictionary, max

I need to find the category, within an array, that holds the "largest" weight. I define the weights in an environment variable:

```
CATEGORY_WEIGHTS = {
  "small_standard": 0,
  "large_standard": 1,
  "small_oversize": 2,
  "medium_oversize": 3,
  "large_oversize": 4
}
```

In this example, the "largest" weighted category would be `large_oversize`.

The array that I'm checking looks like this:

```
categories = [
  "small_oversize",
  "large_standard",
  "small_standard",
  "large_oversize"
]
```

But when I do this, it doesn't return the correct value:

```
max_category = categories.max_by{ |cat| CATEGORY_WEIGHTS[cat] }
```

It returns `small_oversize` instead of `large_oversize`.

Where did I go astray?

Comment: In a hash declaration `"x": y` becomes `:x => y`. For actual string keys: `"x" => y`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using symbols in the hash, but you're trying to access it with strings. Change it to:

```
max_category = categories.max_by{|cat| CATEGORY_WEIGHTS[cat.to_sym]}
```

And here is how you can do it simpler:

```
category_weights = {
  small_standard: 0,
  large_standard: 1,
  small_oversize: 2,
  medium_oversize: 3,
  large_oversize: 4
}

category = category_weights.max_by{|c, w| w}[0]
```

Comment: yep, perfect. thank you! I'll accept answer when it lets me!